# adding data to DOM

Tags: javascript

As far as I've seen, no one has addressed this method specifically because of the document.GetElementsByClassName I'm calling, but I cannot figure why it will not work.  The intent here is to add the value (string) to the page.  I have identified an existing div by class name and simply added a text node which should then display the data item, "Account Name:".  There is obviously something wrong with my syntax or logic but I cannot see it.

Can someone shed some light for me?

```
this.updateUname = function() { 
    var newNode[0] = getElementsByClassName('acc');
    var div = document.createTextNode('div');
    div.innerHTML = "Account Name:";
    newNode.appendChild(div);
    }
```

Thanks, in advance.
ajfbiz

Comment: `var newNode[0]` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`var newNode[0] = getElementsByClassName('acc');`

to

`var newNode = document.getElementsByClassName('acc')[0];`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c2bH4/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create a div element, then you want to use

```
document.createElement("div");
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: OK ... so I added div=document.createElement("div"); .... still not working.  About newMode[0] ... I thought the output of GetElementsByClassName had to be an array??  I'm a newbie to javascript.  So newMode[0] notation is wrong .... actually I've tried it with [0] removed, but it's hard to test when so many problems.